# Unable to open scss file from path without extension in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

In VSCode when I click import path without extension e.g. `@import '../styles/mixins';` I get:
[image]

So I need to use `@import '../styles/mixins.scss';`
Is there any configuration or extension to VSCode to make it work for both - with and without extension?

Comment: I don't believe that's even possible. If your file is `mixins.scss` then you have to import the file `mixins.scss` with this command `@import '../styles/mixins.scss'`. The file `mixins` doesn't exist so you can't run the command `@import '../styles/mixins'`. It's all in the error code, "File Not Found". Since the file doesn't exist, I really doubt any configuration or extension will fix the issue.

Comment: it used to work without any problems some months ago, it's been just some update that made it stop working https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/142836

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible. If your file is `mixins.scss` then you have to import the file mixins.scss with this command `@import '../styles/mixins.scss'`. The file `mixins` doesn't exist so you can't run the command `@import '../styles/mixins'`. It's all in the error code, "File Not Found"